# get column name and values in array at same time from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am looking out for some kind of short code where i should not be repeating the `column names` in database and it should directly be inserted with respective `column name` index to `array value` . Below i have uploaded the image for understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
$query = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE user_id=1;" );
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $query );
print_r( $row );
```

more about [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) on php.net

Answer (score 2):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` rather than `mysql_fetch_row()` and the array will be associative (using the column names as the key) rather than numeric.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE User_ID = 1");

while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  echo $r1['User_ID'] . ': ' . $r1['First_Name'] . ' ' . $r1['Last_Name'] . '<br />';
}
```